# SQL query will not finish

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-optimization

I have the following query -

```
 WITH 
      etl AS 
      (
      SELECT 
         clm.patient_id, clm.npi, clm.provider, clm.start::DATE AS start_dt
      FROM rev
      JOIN data clm
         ON rev.patient_id = clm.patient_id AND rev.claim = clm.CLAIM
      )
      , i AS
      (
      SELECT org_id, etl.npi, pid, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY org_id ORDER BY type, id) AS order       
      FROM   etl
      JOIN   org_identifier 
             ON  etl.npi = org_identifier.npi
             AND etl.provider = org_identifier.pid
             AND type ILIKE 'CARE%'
      )
      SELECT *
      FROM   etl
      JOIN   i 
      ON 
      i.npi = etl.npi AND i.pid = etl.provider AND i.order = 1
```

This is the query plan of the query -

```
Nested Loop  (cost=437.29..437.35 rows=1 width=206)

 Join Filter: ((etl.npi = i.npi) AND (etl.provider = (i.pid)::text))
  CTE etl
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..434.60 rows=1 width=30)
          ->  Seq Scan on rev  (cost=0.00..11.60 rows=160 width=12)
          ->  Index Scan using data_unique on data clm  (cost=0.43..2.63 rows=1 width=34)
                Index Cond: ((patient_id = rev.patient_id) AND (claim = rev.claim))
  CTE ooi
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=2.67..2.69 rows=1 width=64)
          ->  Sort  (cost=2.67..2.67 rows=1 width=56)
                Sort Key: org_identifier.org_id, org_identifier.type, org_identifier.id
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..2.66 rows=1 width=56)
                      ->  CTE Scan on etl etl_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=64)
                      ->  Index Scan using org_identifier_pid_npi on org_identifier  (cost=0.41..2.64 rows=1 width=35)
                            Index Cond: (((pid)::text = etl_1.provider) AND ((npi)::text = etl_1.npi))
                            Filter: ((type)::text ~~* 'CARE%'::text)
  ->  CTE Scan on etl  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=76)
  ->  CTE Scan on i  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=130)
        Filter: (order = 1)
```

How can I change or optimize this query so it finishes running. It has currently been running for 2 hours. I have `VACUUM ANALYZE` the data table. I have checked for locks on the backend and there are none. There are also no other processes updating any of the tables this query is using.

**UPDATE**

```
Nested Loop  (cost=437.29..437.35 rows=1 width=8) (actual 

time=0.037..0.037 rows=0 loops=1)
  Output: i.org_id
  Join Filter: ((etl.npi = i.npi) AND (etl.ccn = (i.pid)::text))
  Buffers: shared hit=43
  CTE etl
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..434.60 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=0 loops=1)
          Output: clm.patient_id, clm.npi, clm.ccn, clm.start
          Buffers: shared hit=43
          ->  Seq Scan on public.rev  (cost=0.00..11.60 rows=160 width=12) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=14 loops=1)
                Output: rev.patient_id, rev.claim, ...other columns...
                Buffers: shared hit=1
          ->  Index Scan using data_unique on public.data clm  (cost=0.43..2.63 rows=1 width=34) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=14)
                Output: clm.claim, clm.patient_id, clm.start, ...other columns...
                Index Cond: ((clm.patient_id = rev.patient_id) AND (clm.claim = rev.claim))
                Buffers: shared hit=42
  CTE i
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=2.67..2.69 rows=1 width=64) (never executed)
          Output: org_identifier.org_id, etl_1.npi, org_identifier.pid, row_number() OVER (?), org_identifier.type, org_identifier.id
          ->  Sort  (cost=2.67..2.67 rows=1 width=56) (never executed)
                Output: org_identifier.org_id, org_identifier.type, org_identifier.id, etl_1.npi, org_identifier.pid
                Sort Key: org_identifier.org_id, org_identifier.type, org_identifier.id
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..2.66 rows=1 width=56) (never executed)
                      Output: org_identifier.org_id, org_identifier.type, org_identifier.id, etl_1.npi, org_identifier.pid
                      Inner Unique: true
                      ->  CTE Scan on etl etl_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=64) (never executed)
                            Output: etl_1.patient_id, etl_1.npi, etl_1.ccn, etl_1.start
                      ->  Index Scan using org_identifier_pid_npi on public.org_identifier  (cost=0.41..2.64 rows=1 width=35) (never executed)
                            Output: org_identifier.id, org_identifier.org_id, org_identifier.pid, org_identifier.type, org_identifier.pid_ca, org_identifier.pid_state, org_identifier.npi
                            Index Cond: (((org_identifier.pid)::text = etl_1.ccn) AND ((org_identifier.npi)::text = etl_1.npi))
                            Filter: ((org_identifier.type)::text ~~* 'CARE%'::text)
  ->  CTE Scan on etl  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=0 loops=1)
        Output: etl.patient_id, etl.npi, etl.ccn, etl.start
        Buffers: shared hit=43
  ->  CTE Scan on i  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=122) (never executed)
        Output: i.org_id, i.npi, i.pid, i.pid_order
        Filter: (i.pid_order = 1)
Planning time: 0.403 ms
Execution time: 0.085 ms
```

Comment: Have you tried putting all "care" providers in a temp table and then joining to that temp table? This code ` SELECT org_id
  ,etl.npi
  ,pid
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
   PARTITION BY org_id ORDER BY type
    ,id
   ) AS
 ORDER
 FROM etl
 JOIN org_identifier ON etl.npi = org_identifier.npi
  AND etl.provider = org_identifier.pid
  AND type ILIKE 'CARE%'` has a bit of smell to me

Comment: @Aron I have not tried that but I do not think that is causing a problem looking at the query plan.

Comment: @eshirvana Added to the question.

Comment: @Aaron it shows your query finishes in 0.085 ms ! isn't that fast enough?

Comment: @eshirvana It is taking 4 hours to finish.